# How can i get value to post as a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command which outputs the users Xbox gamerscore in a simple message. Right now I'm able to retrieve the gamerscore using the Xbox API but I don't know how to get that data into a discord message.

**This is my code right now:**

```
        const authInfo = await this._authenticate();
        const userXuid = await XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerXUID(gamertag, authInfo);

        XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerSettings(gamertag, authInfo, ['Gamerscore']).then(console.info);
    }
```

**And this is what is returned to the console:**

2020-07-07T13:29:07.533242+00:00 app[worker.1]: [ { id: 'GamerScore', value: '78855' } ]

**Conclusion**

So how would I get the value 78855 to send as a discord message? Any help would be greatly appreciated cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerSettings()` is an asynchronouse operation and returns a promise.

Have you tried:

```
const scores = await XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerSettings(gamertag, authInfo, ['Gamerscore']);
const value = scores[0].value;

// the extracted value can now be sent in a discord message.
message.reply(value)
```

Or using the .then() functionality you may update your code in the following way:

```
XboxLiveAPI.getPlayerSettings(gamertag, authInfo, ['Gamerscore']).then((scores) => message.reply(scores[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of objects;

```js
.then((i) => message.reply(i[0].value));
```

This is assuming you're within an event where `message` is defined. Such as:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
   // Code here
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `message.channel.send(i[0].value)`